# Frequency and amplitude estimation with missing samples

Tags: frequency, estimation

My input signal is given by $$ x[n] = A\sin(2\pi f n/F_s + \varphi)$$
The signal is uniformly sampled at a sampling rate of $F_s $[Hz]. However some of the samples are missing. Assume that there are not many missing samples and that their location is known (i.e. I know the timestamp for each sample),  I am interested in estimating $A$ and $f$.

My initial approach is to interpolate the vector and use standard methods (e.g. FFT). Another thought is to perform some kind non-linear regression (which I am unfamiliar with).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think best method for your is to use non-linear regression. These methods do not need to use equidistant data. I answered on similar questions ([fft-bin-interpolation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22003/fft-bin-interpolation-for-low-frequency-with-dc-offset/22006#22006)). Below is citation from this answer:

> If your signal is quite similar to sinus with noise, then I think you can estimate frequency by using fitting or regression methods. Search Internet with keywords: "fit", "regression", "least square" and "sine". You can find a lot of program code, tools and so on. For example (I do not try it) - [sine-function-fit](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41246-sine-function-fit) See also good discussion in StackExchange ["Given a data set, how do you do a sinusoidal regression on paper? What are the equations, algorithms?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301194/given-a-data-set-how-do-you-do-a-sinusoidal-regression-on-paper-what-are-the-e) There are a lot of good books and manuals for fitting/regression. I can recommend classical book  [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/). See chapter "Modeling of Data". Especially  "Fitting Data to a Straight Line" for base understanding and  "Nonlinear Models" for understanding method of solution your problem. It is possible that there are specific methods for sine function.
>
> Implementation of regression in your case can be effective. You must solve minimization problem for system by size of 3 (for amplitude, frequency and phase). Calculation of coefficients of this system is sums of some functions from all your points - O(N).